# Send large files to API via HTTP

Tags: esp32, http

I am making a stream-based radio clock that needs to send snippets of the stream to an external API for music recognition using an ESP-WROOM-32 DevKit.

The snippets that I record are 15 seconds long, which results in a file ~2MB in size (assuming the stream is 128Kbps, MP3). If I try to buffer this in the ESP32's RAM, it will fill it up in no time.

How can I send that snippet via HTTP without overflowing the ESP's RAM?

Comment: Use one of the ESP32s with the 8MB PSRAM?

Comment: Can't you _stream_ the snippets? If you can, then you don't need to store them.

Comment: i don't like shying away from a challenge, but this is more apt for an SBC than an MCU.